# Ajax call doesn't work within click() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to update my page dynamically using ajax and php. The ajax call works fine until I put it within a click() function. The alert works ok

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formbutton").click(function(){
        alert("test");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'url.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#response").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This works fine in debugging:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert("test");
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url.php',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#response").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: whether the alert is working

Comment: Could you show the example that works? Would be easier to spot the differences. Are you sure you have not changed anything else?

Comment: show us how the other code is like, which the ajax call works fine. I mean how do you run this without click function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the button inside a FORM tag?

If that is the case, take into account that the default behavior of a button is to submit the form, probably you don't see the AJAX response because the default event handler of the submit form is executed before the AJAX success handler.

Try to:

- Remove the FORM if you don't need it.
- If you want to keep the form, use a "preventDefault":

  ```
  $('#formbutton').click(function(evt) { evt.preventDefault(); /* ... */ });
  ```
- If you are using a `button` tag, you can also change the type to "button": `<button type="button">`, so you ensure that the browser is not using `type=submit` as default.

Comment: Cool! I saw that you are using the AJAX call to get an HTML... take a look to the jQuery load function: http://api.jquery.com/load/ , it will save you a couple of lines of code :)